# Does mutual fund front-load fee count toward IRA contribution limits?

Tags: united-states, ira, mutual-funds, fees, limits

I want to max out my IRA and I am investing in a mutual fund with 5% front-load fee.

Does that mean that I can contribute $5,500 max for IRA but have real IRA balance $5,500 less $275 = $5,225 as a result?

Or, can contribute $5,789 so my *after fee* balance becomes $5,500?

Our financial adviser said that first case is how it works, but he was not able to point me to any IRS documentation confirming it.

Comment: Can I start with "Don't invest in mutual funds with front-load fees"?  I think your advisor is right - this is effectively a cost to your IRA, so it counts against the limit; the only thing I could imagine would be if you were allowed to pay the front-load fee out of pocket (out of normally taxed income), but I think that's identical (or close enough) to just contributing $5500 then contributing after-tax another $289.

Comment: I asked a similar question [here](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/25080/can-you-use-external-money-to-pay-trading-commissions-in-tax-free-and-tax-deferr).

Comment: Actually, I don't seem to have enough points to mark it as a duplicate, do you mind doing that? Feel free to add your answer too so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Craig W for pointing out to similar question with the links.

From IRS [Publication 590-A](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590a.pdf) (2014 tax year):

> Brokers' commissions. Brokers' commissions paid in
>   connection with your traditional IRA are subject to the contribution
>   limit.

and

> Brokers' commissions. These commissions are part of
>   your IRA contribution and, as such, are deductible subject
>   to the limits.

I wish they did not count them toward contributions. I'd rather deduct net IRA contribution than commissions in this case...

Note that first quote talks specifically about `Traditional IRA` and does not say anything about `Roth IRA`. I might post a separate question about Roth.